# Automatically adding branch name to a homepage comment

Tags: javascript, git, build

This questions a bit vague as I not sure where to start.

Our testers have requested that we add the release branch into a comment on the homepage so they always know which branch they are testing against. Its a Fair enough request.

I can see the use case but I don't want to do this manually, I'd forget to do it and cause more problems. Is there a way to automatically add a git branch name into a comment? This questions woolly I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I think I can do this with node.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-branch-name